# Convert Linq expression to use CompiledQuery

Tags: linq

I am trying to figure out how to convert a Linq expression to a CompiledQuery
here is my existing method that I wanted to convert

```
public IList<Item> GetAllItems()
{
    using (var pos = new ABCEntities())
    {
        var qryAllItems = from itm in pos.Items.Where(o=>o.Is_Inactive==false)
            select itm;

        return qryAllItems.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is Entity Framework because your context class is called ABC *Entities*.

Create a private static field to hold your compiled query delegate, then initialize it using the `CompiledQuery.Compile()` method (I chose to do this is in the field initializer for brevity ... it could have been done in a static constructor, or lazily when it is first called, etc.). Then invoke the delegate when `GetAllItems()` is called.

```
private static Func<ABCEntities, IQueryable<Item>> _activeItemsQuery = 
    CompiledQuery.Compile<ABCEntities, IQueryable<Item>>(
        (pos) => pos.Items.Where(o=>o.Is_Inactive==false));

public IList<Item> GetAllItems()
{
    using (var pos = new ABCEntities())
    {
        return _activeItemsQuery(pos).ToList();
    }
}
```

More on EF Compiled Queries here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx.

I also removed your `from` and `select` because they're not needed when you use that extension method syntax. I could have alternately done:

```
private static Func<ABCEntities, IQueryable<Item>> _activeItemsQuery = 
    CompiledQuery.Compile<ABCEntities, IQueryable<Item>>(
        (pos) => from itm in pos.Items where itm.Is_Inactive == false select itm;
```

But I personally prefer to use the extension methods most of the time.